# Keras GAN Batch Training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I have looked at some code/tutorials (tutorial: [1](https://medium.com/@mattiaspinelli/simple-generative-adversarial-network-gans-with-keras-1fe578e44a87) and [2](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/gan/gan.py)) for implementing a GAN in Keras.

Both do batch training as follows:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # ---------------------
    # Train Discriminator
    # ---------------------
    # Select a random batch of images

    # Generate a batch of new images

    # Train the discriminator

    # ---------------------
    # Train Generator
    # ---------------------
```

In the above code (taken from line 92 in (2)), they loop over all epochs, but then for each epoch, only train on one batch. As I understand, for each epoch, we should train on many batches; so that we go through the whole dataset. For example, if we have 100 samples and a batch size of 10, then for each epoch, we train on 10 batches of size 10. Why is it that in this code, they only train on a single batch for each epoch? Sorry if this is a basic question; I am quite new to machine learning.

Answer (score 1):

When you do GAN there are few things that change from normal neural network training.

1. Your input data evolves through time. The artificial images from the Generator network change at each update of the weights in the network.
2. You have to train both networks simultaneously. It is pointless to train the discriminator on a lot of data, if you then update the generator. Because this changes the data distribution from which the discriminator learns. For this reason you might want to update both networks frequently. So it can be preferred to make updates of both networks each batch.

I don't know why they call this update an epoch, I guess you could disagree with the naming. But remember that epoch and batch have a meaning when the training data is fixed. In this case it is not, so maybe they just call it epoch because they lack of a better word.